# Drag a file in kivy window and loading main class functions doesn't add widgets

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

Iam made a mini-csv editor and i want to add a drag n drop support for it, I tried the using on_dropfile event, which works, but if any add_widget statements executed on it, it draws totally nothing, here's the code:-

```
class CsvEditor(Widget):

    grid = ObjectProperty(None)
    records = []
    row_len = 0

    def load(self, drag=""):
        global row_len

        if drag == "":
            filepath = filechooser.open_file(title="Pick a CSV file..", filters=[("Comma-separated Values", "*.csv")])[0]

        else:
            filepath = drag

        cell_num = 0
        with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:

            self.grid.children = []
            for row in csv.reader(f, encoding='utf-8'):
                row_len = len(row)
                self.grid.cols = row_len
                for i in row:
                    if cell_num == 0 or cell_num % 3 == 0:
                        self.grid.add_widget(TextInput(multiline=False, text=i, width=50, font_name='C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Fonts\\MEIRYO.TTC', size_hint_x=None))
                        cell_num += 1
                    else:
                        self.grid.add_widget(TextInput(multiline=False, text=i, font_name='C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Fonts\\MEIRYO.TTC'))
                        cell_num += 1

    def on_file_drop(self, window, drag_file_path):
        self.load(drag=drag_file_path)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.bind(on_dropfile=CsvEditor().on_file_drop)
        return CsvEditor()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

the .kv file:-

```
<CsvEditor>:
    grid: grid

    canvas:

        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1

        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            width: 500
            height: 50
            size_hint: 1, None

            Button:
                size_hint: None, 1
                size: 80, 50
                text: "Open..."
                on_release: root.load(drag="")

            Button:
                size_hint: None, 1
                size: 80, 50
                text: "Save"
                on_release: root.save_file()

            Button:
                size_hint: None, 1
                size: 80, 50
                text: "Save as..."
                on_release: root.save_as()

        ScrollView:
            scroll_type: ['bars']
            bar_width: '15dp'
            scroll_wheel_distance: 100
            GridLayout:
                id: grid
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint_y : None
                height: self.minimum_height
                row_default_height: 60
```

Calling the load() function from the .kv file works and draw all the TextInputs. but calling it from the on_file_drop function executes everything in load() normally but all the add_widget calls draw nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Window.bind(on_dropfile=CsvEditor().on_file_drop)
return CsvEditor()
```

You've bound `on_dropfile` to the on_file_drop method of a CsvEditor instance, but then tell your gui to display a new, unrelated CsvEditor instance.

You need to bind the behaviour to the instance that you are displaying, e.g.

```
editor = CsvEditor()
Window.bind(on_dropfile=editor.on_file_drop)
return editor
```

Comment: Worked!,  I can't believe it was that simple